# Does an error stop making a program?

Tags: error-handling, preprocessor

For example, if I incorrectly #include something and the preprocessor gets an error, does it still go through the compiler, assembler, and linker?

Comment: An example? How do you mean "incorrectly" exactly?

Comment: Like if I type #includ instead of #include the preprocessor gives an error.

Comment: Most likely won't compile at all, but it may depend on IDE.  You can try it and find out, right?

Answer (score 0):

Make a small program which contains only this line:

```
     #includerr (stdio.h)
```

And tell me what happens...

Can you see any `.OBJ`, or `.O` , or `.EXE` or `a.out` files? If you can see `.O` or `.OBJ`, the file has been compiled and assembled. If you see any `.EXE` or `a.out` files, the file has been linked to the standard libraries and produced an executable.

---

If you cannot see any of these files, manually try to compile the file. For example, under Linux you can do:

`gcc -c -S file.c`

Will compile and produce an assembly file, then will stop. If you can see the `.S` file after this, and the file is not empty, `file.c` has been succesfully compiled and translated into assembler.

If you do:

`gcc -c file.c`

Will try to compile and assemble `file.c` resulting in `file.o` if it successes.

If you do:

`gcc file.c`

Will try to compile, assemble, and link `file.c` resulting in `a.out` if it successes.

Comment: Yup it runs through compiler and all. Thank you!